# Is the UK asking for increased influence over the EU post-Brexit?

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, brexit

Recently I heard a BBC correspondent speaking on Radio 4 about why the UK is finding it so hard to get what it wants from the Brexit negotiations. The correspondent said that EU politicians had told him right at the start that they couldn't allow the UK to increase its influence and power over the EU.

Currently the UK has a nominal 1/28th influence over the EU, i.e. it is equal partners with the other 27 members. In practice soft power and the size of its economy give it much more, but doubtless it is far from the equal of all 27 others combined.

Post Brexit if the UK and EU were equal partners in a trade deal, that would seem to give the UK a massive increase in influence over EU policy and the other members. The BBC correspondent said that the EU would not allow that to happen, implying that the final deal would have to leave the UK with very little choice when it comes to dealing with the EU.

Is the UK seeking to increase its influence over the EU with the deals it is seeking, e.g. the Chequers proposal or anything else that the government has put forward?

Comment: You might want to double-check the question title.

Comment: The current 1/28th measure is only correct under some circumstances, since the definition of "equal" varies. For example the number of MEPs a country gets is roughly proportional to its population. Similarly, qualified majority voting requires 55% of the countries representing 65% of the population.

Comment: @origimbo that's all true. I don't really want to get hung up on the exact numbers though, which is why I said "nominal 1/28th". The point is that the UK is accused of some kind of power grab, attempting to obtain a better position outside the club than in it.

Comment: @user if you don't have a better position outside the club than in it, why would you leave? Though the important point is probably that the EU is about more than trade. And it is in non-trade matters where UK control would shift most obviously from "EU shared" to "UK alone".

Comment: Sounds like you consider ability to not agree to a deal as influence. It is only superficially so. Actual influence means getting deal, trade or otherwise, that benefits you more than other party. "No deal" ability runs both ways, after leaving, UK might want pie from the sky, that in no way implies they have any way of actually getting it as it's EU that can simply refuse such ludicrous demands. Considering that UK needs access to EU markets more than the opposite, UKs influence over EU is going to sharply drop; getting present day-like access would cost them way more than it costs now.

Comment: @Jontia good question, I'd like an answer to why the UK should leave when it will be worse off outside the club. So far I have not heard anyone offer a good one.

Comment: @Miech for example May was talking about some kind of partnership where the UK would have "input" over changes made to EU rules that affect it due to some kind of customs arrangement or having some limited single market access. At the moment that input is a nominal 1/28th... But brexiteers seem to be demanding more, stuff like jurisdiction for UK courts (and thus UK law) etc.

Comment: Re "Post Brexit if the UK and EU were equal partners in a trade deal, that would seem to give the UK a massive increase in influence over EU policy and the other members. " Like Japan or Canada has? How is that a massive influence? The EU has offered a free trade deal like that to the UK [already](https://euobserver.com/uk-referendum/141238). Of course, what the UK wants (Chequers) is a different matter.

Comment: @Fizz but the UK wants much more than a Canada/Japan style deal, that's the point. A Canada style deal would be an economic disaster for the UK.

Answer (score 11):

Yes. If the EU accepted the [Chequers deal](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/723460/CHEQUERS_STATEMENT_-_FINAL.PDF) this would leave the UK with more power than the remaining members of the EU. A good summary is the BBC [article on the subject](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/uk-politics-44749993) but I'll quote the document directly for the remaining of this answer (emphasis is mine).

---

1) The UK agrees to use the common rulebook but wants the same power as before brexit in negotiating the standards. Also the UK wants to retain the possibility of refusing to follow those same standards. It mentions that it understands that this would have consequences but, at this point in the document (see the next point) presents no legal framework to deal with it effectively leaving the consequences in legal limbo. Finally it puts "services" out of the deal.

> I. POSITION   ON  THE FUTURE  RELATIONSHIP
>
> a. **The  UK  and the EU  would   maintain    a common    rulebook    for all goods** including   agri-food,  with the    UK  making  an  upfront choice  to  commit  by  treaty  to  ongoing harmonisation   with    EU  rules on    goods,  covering    only     those  necessary    to provide 
>   for   frictionless     trade  at   the    border.
>
> (...)
>
> **The  UK would   of  course  continue     to play    a   strong   role   in  shaping  the    international   standards    that    underpin** 
>   them, and Parliament  would   have    oversight   of  the incorporation of
>   these  rules into  the    UK’s    legal   order –
>   **with    the ability to  choose  not to  do  so, recognising that    this    would have consequences.**
>
> (...)
>
> **We  would   strike different arrangements for   services,   where   it  is  in  our interests to     have    regulatory 
>   flexibility,**     recognising the     UK  and     the     EU  will    not     have
>   current    levels  of access  to  each    other’s markets

2) It mentions that the regulation would be jointly done with UK and EU courts but only considering the rules the UK agreed to follow of the rulebook.

> c.
>   **The UK  and the EU  would   establish   a   joint   institutional   > framework to  provide for the consistent interpretation   and application  of UK-EU   agreements**    by   both parties.  This     would   be  done    in 
>   the   UK  by  UK  courts, and in  the EU  by  EU  courts  –
>   with  due regard  paid    to  EU  case    law **in    areas    where   the     UK** **continued    to apply    a   common  rulebook.**

3) The UK wants to collect EU and UK tariffs in order to be able to maintain different rules depending on the partner country (organization).

> d. The     UK  and     the     EU  would   work    together    on  the     phased 
>   introduction   of  a   new     Facilitated     Customs    Arrangement
>   that  would   remove  the need    for customs checks  and controls    between 
>   the   UK  and the EU  as  if  a   combined    customs territory.  **The   UK  would   apply   the UK’s    tariffs and** **trade    policy  for     goods   intended    for     the     UK,     and     the     EU’s tariffs    and     trade   policy  for     goods   intended    for     the     EU**    - becoming  operational     in  stages  as  both    sides   complete    the
>   necessary preparations.   This    would   enable  the UK  to  control its own tariffs for trade   with    the rest    of  the world   and ensure  businesses  paid    the right   or  no  tariff  - in    the vast    majority    of  cases   upfront, and    otherwise   through a   repayment   mechanism.

4) No longer follow common Agriculture and Fisheries policy:

> d. mean    that    the     UK  will    leave   the     Common  Agricultural
>   Policy     and     Common  Fisheries   Policy  – taking    back    control     of UK   waters  as  an  independent     coastal     state   and     designing   a  domestic agricultural   policy  that    works   in  the best    interests   of  the UK;

5) No longer accept the jurisdiction of the [CJEU](https://europa.eu/european-union/about-eu/institutions-bodies/court-justice_en) (Court of Justice of the European Union):

> g.
>   restore   the supremacy   of  UK  courts, **ending    the jurisdiction    of  the CJEU    in  the UK**,   with    no  more preliminary    references  from    UK  courts, but committing  that    UK  courts  would   pay due regard
>   to     the     **CJEU’s    jurisprudence   where   the     UK  had     chosen  to** **apply    a   common  rulebook**  to  ensure  consistent interpretation;

6) The UK wants to leave the free mobility of EU citizens out of the deal:

> h.
>   **end free    movement,   giving  the UK  back    control over    how many    people  enter   the country;**

7) Ending the financial contributions to the EU:

> j.
>   end   vast    annual  payments    to  the EU  budget, with    appropriate contributions   for joint   action  in specific  areas,  such    as  science     and     innovation,     releasing  funds    for     domestic    priorities  – in    particular our long-term   plan    for the NHS;

---

[Michel Barnier dismissed the proposal almost immediately](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2018/jul/20/france-minister-nathalie-loiseau-brexit-concessions-theresa-may-commons). Many of the points of the agreement would leave the UK with far more power than a normal EU member which pay contributions, follows EU court jurisdiction, follows the freedom of movement principle, and cannot cherry pick which sectors to apply the rules.

The document is also fairly [populist](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Populism) often making unnecessary remarks (that almost look like campaign banners) where none was needed. It clearly seems like a document for internal consumption and trying to appease the more nationalist factions of the Tory party.

> - *mean    that    the     UK  will    leave   the     Common  Agricultural    Policy  and     Common  Fisheries   Policy  – taking    back    control     of 
>     UK     waters  as  an  independent     coastal     state   and     designing   a
>
>     domestic
>     agricultural  policy  that    works   in  the best    interests   of  the UK;*
> - *end    free    movement,   giving  the UK  back    control over    how many    people  enter   the country;*
> - *restore    the supremacy   of  UK  courts, ending  the jurisdiction    of  the CJEU    in  the UK*
> - *end    vast    annual  payments    to  the EU  budget, with    appropriate contributions   for joint   action  in
>     specific   areas,  such    as  science     and     innovation,     releasing
>
>     funds  for     domestic    priorities*

Comment: Your answer (actually Barnier's) also answers a qurestion that was posed before  there was offical EU rection https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/32090/uk-chequers-and-facilitated-customs-arrangement

Comment: @Fizz I personally think Barnier was very diplomatic in his response. Currently some members of the UK cabinet have been trying to negotiate directly with the member states (something I find regrettable) but I have doubts it will work. I do agree with the EU commission that members must start preparing for the no deal scenario. And I also must admit that I was extremely disappointed with the chequers deal. Not only it proposed things that could effectively lead to the breaking on union, but it also had a far more inflammatory tone that I was expecting to see in this kind of document.

Comment: @armatita could you perhaps refocus your answer what specific ares and ways the UK will have more power/influence than it currently does under this proposal?

Comment: @user It's on the first paragraph of the third block. All of the answer can be reduced to this. To participate in the single market, you have to follow the four freedoms (goods, services, capital, and people). Also everyone relies on the EU Court of Justice (to avoid member states creating their own rules). The UK wants to participate in the single market but have power to follow or not the rules at their own discretion, create their own framework for services, not pay contributions, end the free movement of people, etc. No one has this.

Comment: @user-Basically, the UK will actually have a say in matters related to the UK. That is far more power than they have now. As for more power over the EU, there is none, unless you call claiming the power to reject rules imposed upon you that you never agreed with to be influencing more power over the EU.

Comment: @Dunk That is incorrect. Even if the UK would stand only by WTO rules it would still need to follow [WTO Arbitration](https://www.wto.org/english/tratop_e/dispu_e/arbitrations_e.htm). Having an external impartial arbitrator is common to every trade agreement (see [Nafta for example](https://www.nafta-sec-alena.org/Home/Dispute-Settlement/Overview-of-the-Dispute-Settlement-Provisions)). No significant trade block will allow the UK to self-arbitrate in any meaningful trade agreement. Whatever the choice the UK makes it will always need to allow the superiority of international institutions.

Comment: @armatita-Which part is incorrect? Your arbitrary reframing the context to support your claim (ie. only by WTO rules). As it stands, the UK has no say in rules imposed upon it by the EU. Brexit gives the UK the freedom to reject rules it is not willing to abide by. Of course this also implies they need to abide by the rules they agree to abide by in negotiations with the EU or WTO. The key difference being that they AGREED to abide by those rules by choice as opposed to being told which rules they have to follow. That is quite a huge distinction.

Comment: @Dunk *"As it stands, the UK has no say in rules imposed upon it by the EU."* It's sentences like this that make me question if the Brexit vote was an informed one. EU law is decided by national representatives (one from each member, and chosen by the people you voted for), and by MEPs you also voted for. Further the EU treaties require ratification from every single member (that means approval by 100% of the members). This isn't exactly new or secret information, yet somehow I'm the one being accused of arbitrarily reframing contexts.